# fprintf not working when runned by another application

Tags: c, printf

i have a C console application that write a text to a file:

```
 FILE *f;
 f = fopen("out", "w");
 fprintf(f, "%s","My Text");
 rewind(f);
 fclose(f);
```

when i run it from explorer it works fine, but when i run it using another application the file does not create and the text not saved

even with the administrator rights

can any one help me ?

Comment: don't run as admin, set up a new unprivileged account (not your normal account), to run your C experiments in.

Comment: put an absolute file name like `"C:\\out"` (windows) or `"/home/out"` (linux), to avoid `out` being created in the other application working directory

Comment: could be your present working directory. The program may be or trying to write to an unexpected place.

Comment: side note: I don't think you need the rewind.

Comment: Just for kicks, send the results of `getcwd()` to stdout just to see where things are going. I've a feeling you're in for a surprise.

Comment: You might like to test the result of the call to `fopen()`. It return `NULL` on failure.

Comment: @Antoine `/home/username/out` for Linux, Unix, Qnx, mac OSX ... (and I an not sure that MS-Windows lets you write into root of C: (any more) without admin privalages.)

Comment: like @alk says, check your return values. Put the fprintf in an if, and an exit(not zero) in the else.

Comment: @richard: indeed, but the OP mentionned admin rights so I didn't bother ;)

Comment: What other application are you trying to run it from?

Comment: Thank you! That's the thing that i've missed !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `out` file is a relative path and it may be set e.g. to your third-party application directory. Or maybe it changes its current directory to something else and it results your app saving `out` there? If you're not sure, you can always try to pass absolute path to your `out` file.

Comment: Exactly the problem!
Thank you very much!